# Stateless front-end grails server?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have a single grails (3.3.5) web server, and I am interested in improving the availability and I'd like to add another server and put a load balancer in front of it.

Rather than share sessions between servers, or use sticky sessions, i'd like to know if there is a good way to have a session-less front-end server.  I don't use sessions for anything other than using spring-security to validate the session token that it is using to identify the user.

I'd like to find a token based authentication system suitable for the front-end such that the token is safe and sufficient for identifying the current user.

I've seen the grails-spring-security-rest plugin which looks promising, but it seems like everyone is using it for back-end rest api calls.  Is it also suitable for front-end authentication when you aren't storing application data in the webapp session?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the `session` objects in your controller then tomcat will not create any sessions for you.

Also you can define your controllers to be

```
static singleton = true
```

then they will be instantiated not on per-request basis.

Now, if you still want to use sessions, you can use something like [Cookie Sessions](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/double16/cookie-session) and keep your data inside the cookies instead of tomcat's memory.

I haven't used the `grails-spring-security-rest`, but you should be able to tweak `spring-security-core` to be session-less. You should set `scr.allowSessionCreation` to `false` and use `remember-me`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Grails is built on Spring Boot, you can access all the features of Spring Session (https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.x/reference/html5/), which includes the ability to share session data between server instances with some data store instead of keeping it in memory.

In those docs you'll find this pointer to a guide with a Grails 3.1 example that uses Redis as the store. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/2.0.3.RELEASE/samples/misc/grails3

Answer (score 0):

> Is it also suitable for front-end authentication when you aren't storing application data in the webapp session?

Yes, you can use JWT tokens in your front-end. You need to properly configure the security filters of your controllers so that they are not using cookie for authentication but they are looking for JWT.

See : http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_plugin_configuration for configuration of endpoints that should validate JWT tokens.

Have a look at https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-grails-sample/wiki/3-basic-auth for a stateless example with Angular.